# package org.hibernate does not exist import org.hibernate.*

Tags: java, hibernate

I have downloaded Hibernate package and copied `hibernate3.jar` file and other `jar`s files to my classpath. That is, `C:\Program Files\Java\hibernate-distribution-3.6.4.Final` in my computer.

My Java code:

```
import org.hibernate.*;    
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateTestDriver    
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration(); 
        cfg.addResource("hello/Message.hbm.xml"); 
        cfg.setProperties( System.getProperties() );
        SessionFactory sessions = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        // Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Session session = sessions.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Message message = new Message("Hello World");
        session.save(message);
    }
}
```

When I compile it below error comes:

```
"..: package org.hibernate does not exist import org.hibernate.*;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile, you need to include the Hibernate jar in your classpath. Just putting the directory is not enough. You can do this by adding arguments to the javac command:

```
javac -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\hibernate-distribution-3.6.4.Final\hibernate3.jar" HibernateTestDriver.java
```

You can also set the CLASSPATH environment variable to include it.

If you are using an IDE, you should set the project so it includes the Hibernate jar in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try ranaming the file hibernate3.jar to hibernate3.zip and extract the contents. The classes provided by that JAR file will be in the com/hibernate/ folder. If you don't see a com/hibernate folder then you must be using the wrong JAR or you might need to add more JARs to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Jboss, add the Jboss lib in classpath.

if using maven include jboss lib in build classpath, else add as dependency in maven with scope provided.

Answer (score -1):

I had to add the jars individually to the compile time libraries as jar files not as libraries. Weird. I am using Netbeans.

This method did not resolve the issue..
javac -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\hibernate-distribution-3.6.4.Final\hibernate3.jar" HibernateTestDriver.java

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)